# Extensions are turned off after reboot

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 with Gnome 3.10. My problem is that every time I reboot the OS all the shell extensions are turned off. The weird thing is that their settings are kept. They are just turned off and I have to re-enable them every time. How can I make them persistent.

Thanks

**Update**

Today Ubuntu 13.10 was officially released and after I upgraded, my problem is still there. Here is my system info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-desktop 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

**Sidenote** - Can someone please tell me at least were the settings of the state of the extensions (on/off) are stored? I have removed all the extensions

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
```

and I installed the ones I use. So I am thinking of creating a cronjob and enabling all of them everytime the system boots. At least until i find how to fix this.

Comment: Can you please explain why the downvote?

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: I know it's a bit late but I implemented a solution script in python if the one above don't satisfy you. [https://github.com/loric-/enableGnomeExtensions.py](https://github.com/loric-/enableGnomeExtensions.py) Hope that the problem will be fixed soon by the way.

Comment: This is a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1236749

Comment: Yeah, that bug is finally fixed!

Comment: your script enable all the extensions and not everyone want that.

Answer (score 20):

This works in Gnome 3.8.4, and should work later versions.

Set all the extensions you want to be on.
Then run:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
```

This should come up with something like

```bash
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
['user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com', 'CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com']
```

Copy the output, and then run `gnome-session-properties`

Press add, and then enter the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['use... ...blogspot.com']"` - However, as has been kindly pointed out, change `get` to `set` when entering in the command box, like in the picture below. PUT THE DOUBLE QUOTES IN, OTHERWISE THIS WILL NOT WORK (If not sure, test the command in the terminal first - if no feedback is given, it worked).

**EDIT:** For newer versions without `gnome-session-properties`, you need will probably need to manually make a [.desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) file in `~/.config/autostart` - some GUI tools may be available via Gnome Tweak Tool or similar.

**For Example:**

[image: Description 1]

Then make sure that this is on:

[image: Description 2]

Now, every time you login, it should run a command to restore all the extensions!

**N.B.** If you make changes to your activated extensions, this would need to be updated.

---

To automate this process, this script seems to work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
active_extensions=$(gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions)
autostart_file=$HOME/.config/autostart/restore-extensions.desktop
echo -e "Currently active extensions:\n\e[34m$active_extensions\e[0m"
echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application" > $autostart_file
echo Exec=gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions \"$active_extensions\" >> $autostart_file
echo -e "Hidden=false\nNoDisplay=false\nX-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true\nName=Restore Extensions\nComment=Restore enabled extensions on login" >> $autostart_file
echo "Command to restore currently active extensions added to $HOME/.config/autostart/restore-extensions.desktop"
exit
```

Save the script to `~/.local/bin/extension-update`, make it executable *(either set it in the file's Properties window, or run `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/extension-update`)*.

Then every time you run `extension-update`, it will update an autostart file at `~/.config/autostart/restore-extensions.desktop` *(it will likely be different a different autostart entry if you created one manually as above, so if you created one manually you may want to delete that)* - you can check in `gnome-session-properties` to make sure.

Comment: Hello, @Qasim, does this solve your problem?

Comment: The right line in wilf answer would be gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['use... ...blogspot.com']" (changed "get" to "set", enabling the extensions). (Sorry for bad english).

Comment: Thats a great solution! I use it, when gnome crashes and the extensions are all disabled

Comment: Same script rewritten in Python: https://gist.github.com/sirex/ddf64bb5697271f8da02

Answer (score 9):

Edit: Selecting 'System Default' instead of 'gnome' in login screen seems to work for me

This is known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1236749

Seems like related to TopIcons extension, try disabling this for now: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/

Comment: I have the same problem that @sijoune has. I have the problem irrespective of whether TopIcons is installed.

Comment: I removed the TopIcons and the problem hasn't gone. In my Arch installation though everything works flawlessly... weird.

Comment: I see that if I first login to cinnamon, and then to gnome shell, then the extensions are enabled.

Comment: Same i am having the same problem

Comment: For those who won't get a desktop environment when selecting the "System Default", try the following on a terminal and reboot: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome'

Answer (score 4):

On login menu, set option to "system default" instead of "gnome or classic", extensions should now stay enabled after reboot.
Worked for me!﻿

Comment: Not working if you decide to enable automatic login after.

Comment: For those who won't get a desktop environment when selecting the "System Default", try the following on a terminal and reboot: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session session-name 'gnome'

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem (in openSUSE, but may be the same for you) by deleting the dconf key for enabled extensions, restarting the shell or logging out, and then re-activating the extensions in tweak tool.

Some extensions in dconf weren't actually installed... seems to have been the problem, since it's working now...

Hope that helps.