# Gnome shell extensions are disabled after reboot

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 with Gnome 3.14 from the Gnome 3 PPA's. I have had the persistent problem for about a year now where whenever I log out I lose all of my enabled extensions apart from Media Player. Previously I managed to get around this by enabling each of the extensions at start up using "gnome-session-manager", but this has now disappeared from Gnome 3.14 since it has been replaced by right click options on the dash. I also tried defaulting my boot session to "default session" which has worked for some people as a solution.

There now seems to be no work around for this very annoying and persistent problem with Gnome. It has been a lurking issue for at least a year now with many users effected and nothing but the load at boot workaround on offer. How such a chronic bug can be allowed to sit for over a year is frankly beyond me.

Has anyone got any fresh ideas for a more permanent solution to this Gnome bug ?

Stephen

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/359958/extensions-are-turned-off-after-reboot

Answer (score 5):

Here's a workaround in the spirit of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/367590/13884). This works at least for 3.12. The idea is to export a list of the extensions you want active, then write a script that activate them at boot.

**Getting extension list**

First, activate the extensions you want active. We then generate a list with those:

In terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`), run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
```

It returns a list with your currently active extensions a la

```
['Bottom_Panel@rmy.pobox.com', 'impatience@gfxmonk.net']
```

**Setting extensions**

To activate exactly the extensions in the list, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions ['extension_1',  'extension_2', 'extension_3']
```

but with your own list, naturally :)

**Script to set extensions on boot**

To automate on boot, create a script running that command.

1. Go to e.g. your home folder, and create a new empty file. Name it `script_name.sh` (only the extension matters). Start the file name with a full stop `.` if you want it to be hidden.
2. In that file, write

```
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions ['extension_1',  'extension_2', 'extension_3']
```

Then save the file, of course :)

3. Make the file executable e.g. by `right click > Properties > Permissions > Check "Allow executing file as program"`
   Alternatively, change the permissions from terminal by running `chmod ugo+x script_name.sh` in the script's folder.
4. Make it on system start up (I don't know how else to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290652/1654116)): in `~/.config/autostart/` create a file called `some_name2.desktop` and in it put

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=your_prefered_name_here
Exec=/home/your_user_name/.script_name.sh
# Terminal=false
Type=Application
Hidden=false
StartupNotify=false
Name[en_US]=your_prefered_name_here
```

The path after `Exec=` should be to where the script you created in step 2 is. Again, save the file :)

Maybe immediately or else after boot, you should see the script in Gnome Tweak Tool under Startup Applications. It should also run on startup.

**Activating and Deactivating Extensions**

If you want to change which extensions are run, you should re-generate the list, then insert the new list in the script run.

**Final Words**

I hope this works in 3.14, too.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this is what did the trick for me.  No problems after that.

Comment: adding to Ramsus's (https://askubuntu.com/a/555704/1561095) answer, you may also want to try de-disabling user extensions: ``` gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions false``` if just turning them back on doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Run in terminal: `rm -rd ~/.cache`
2. Reboot system
3. Re-enable your extensions (it should persist across reboots now)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, running Ubuntu 14.10 with GNOME 3.14 from the GNOME 3 PPAs. So I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359958/extensions-are-turned-off-after-reboot), but the real challenge for me was to find the setting to select <kbd>System Default</kbd> instead of <kbd>GNOME</kbd> on Ubuntu GNOME's login screen

[image: Ubuntu GNOME login screen]

Moreover due to [Topicons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/), other extensions are still not activated on login.

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't apply to new user accounts which suggests its a problem caused by retained Gnome settings files from upgraded previous versions of Gnome Shell.

I will investigate resetting the account settings.

---

Tried resetting all the Gnome User account details for my main user. This didn't work so its not account specific.

Comment: I had the problem as well, but I have not updated Gnome Shell yet (pretty new installation).

Answer (score 0):

For me, all Gnome extensions where globally disabled (maybe by some shortcut?).

They can easily be re-enabled on the [Gnome Extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/).

[image]