# gnome extension disable automatically after boot

Tags: crash, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
- GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Sometimes (1 out of 2) when I log in, the first thing that happens is that something crashes (it seems to be gnome-shell) and all extensions that I had are disabled.

I need to manually go and enable them again.

It looks similar to this problem, but it is not the same:
[Gnome shell extensions are disabled after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533718/gnome-shell-extensions-are-disabled-after-reboot)

Any tips on what to look for? I hate that it is crashing on log in. I would not mind upgrading gnome if someone provides a reliable/secure PPA.

Comment: Which extensions and how did you install them ? Disable all extensions and enable one at a time to see which one is the problem. Check the logs.

Comment: Debug - https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Debugging

Comment: Extensions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425616/how-to-test-debug-gnome-shell-extensions-is-there-any-tool-for-that