# Gnome shell extensions switched off after hibernation

Tags: 16.04, gnome, suspend, hibernate, gnome-shell-extension

Hello ubuntu community,

I am generally new to Linux and I've encountered a new problem recently for which I cannot find any related questions here.

It's been two days since hibernation would turn off all gnome extensions after waking the computer up. It's fairly easy to fix it by opening the gnome tweak tool and switching all extensions on again, but it consumes time and would prefer not to be bothered by it on a daily basis.

I'm not exactly sure what may have caused this, I've been trying several methods to solve my wifi random disconnection problem and maybe accidentaly changed a file during that process. Or maybe a recent update in all extensions.

I'm not sure what kind of information I should provide you to help me.
Working on a Lenovo Thinkpad E470 with Ubuntu 16.04 installed with GNOME Shell 3.18.5.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Best,
neko

Comment: Probably related to this Q&A: [Extensions are turned off after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359958/extensions-are-turned-off-after-reboot). And this: [Gnome shell extensions are disabled after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533718/gnome-shell-extensions-are-disabled-after-reboot).

Comment: thank you for the comment. I tried the suggestions in the links, but it seems to be a different problem. I also noticed that it relaunches all the programs that were open after waking up from hibernation.